# Merging MS sql server (aspnetdb) tables, stored procedures etc.. with my own database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, database-design, asp.net-membership

I'm using asp.net default database created on website template (aspnetdb.mdf) and membership class for users. And for the additional information related to my website i'm using another database (mydata.mdf).

What i want to do is to combine these databases into one, and to access them via one connection string. Since getting the data from mydata.mdf then selecting the user info from aspnetdb.mdf according to it is a pain.

What is the best way to achieve this, considering both databases have lots of stored procedures and FK relationships.

I've found some articles telling aspnet_regsql.exe is the way but couldn't find any tutorial and how to execute it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you need to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` against your database to setup the tables and sprocs.

Its a wizard, so it does a good job guiding you through the process.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more information.  There's a chart near the bottom of the page that gives location of the file depending on the version of the framework that you are using.

Comment: This was the fastest solution i've ever got. I'm still thinking how i missed to see that it has a UI in new version, and didn't think of searching msdn about it. Thanks man worked amazing! The only thing left to use the default membership class as before is to change the connection string right?

Comment: Change the connection string, or define your own and change the provider configuration to use it.  You **may** need use `<remove />` to remove the default provider and connection strings if you have problems.

Comment: Thank you! i think i managed to modify everything to my use, hopefully i'll have no problem. Many thanks again!